# having difficulties using setGravity with Toasts

Tags: java, android

I'm a complete noob learning my way through java.

I'm trying to use setGravity to push my Toast to the top of the page but having a lot of difficulties.

If i use the line Toast.setGravity (TOP, 30, 30); then TOP comes up as an error, I use Alt+Ent and it produces an import
import static android.view.Gravity.TOP;

This allows it to recognise TOP but then when i run it tells me that it cannot reference Gravity and Show() from static context.

I've also added import android.view.Gravity; but that just comes up as unused.

What am I doing wrong?

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQhsY.png)

Comment: post code here not snapshot of code...

Answer (score 0):

> import android.view.Gravity;
>
> import android.widget.Toast;

Try this

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Your Message!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,30, 30);
t.show();
```